# FactoryGirl deletes all users in database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, pagination, factory-bot, railstutorial.org

In Rails Tutorial 2nd Edition by Hartl
When running `rspec` tests the `pagination` block in `user_pages_spec.rb` is deleting **all** users in the development database instead of just the users created by `FactoryGirl`. Of course this causes other test to fail now that there aren't anymore users in the database.

user_pages_spec.rb

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe "User pages" do

subject { page }

describe "index" do

let(:user) { FactoryGirl.create(:user) }

before(:each) do
  sign_in user
  visit users_path
end

it { should have_title('All users') }
it { should have_content('All users') }

describe "pagination" do
  before(:all) { 30.times { FactoryGirl.create(:user) } }
  after(:all)  { User.delete_all }

  it { should have_selector('div.pagination') }

  it "should list each user" do
    User.paginate(page: 1).each do |user|
      expect(page).to have_selector('li', text: user.name)
    end
  ...
```

Gemfile

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
ruby '1.9.3'

gem 'rails', '4.0.0'
gem 'bootstrap-sass', '2.3.2.0'
gem 'bcrypt-ruby', '3.0.1'
gem 'faker', '1.1.2'
gem 'will_paginate', '3.0.4'
gem 'bootstrap-will_paginate', '0.0.9'
gem 'pg', '0.15.1'
gem 'activeresource', '4.0.0'

group :development, :test do
  gem 'rspec-rails', '2.13.1'
  gem 'annotate',  '~> 2.5.0'
end

group :test do
  gem 'selenium-webdriver', '2.0.0'
  gem 'capybara', '2.1.0'
  gem 'factory_girl_rails', '4.2.0'
end

gem 'sass-rails', '4.0.0'
gem 'uglifier', '2.1.1'
gem 'coffee-rails', '4.0.0'
gem 'jquery-rails', '2.2.1'
gem 'turbolinks', '1.1.1'
gem 'jbuilder', '1.0.2'

group :doc do
  gem 'sdoc', '0.3.20', require: false
end

group :production do
  gem 'pg', '0.15.1'
  gem 'rails_12factor'
end
```

Comment: You should be using a different test database than you're using for development.

Comment: "before(:each) blocks are run before each example before(:all) blocks are run once before all of the examples in a group" – https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/v/2-0/docs/hooks/before-and-after-hooks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this.

```
30.times do 
  User.last.destroy
end
```

In place of

```
User.delete_all
```

This will delete all the 30 users created by FactoryGirl. But will work only if you are not creating more users in between.

**Update**

The above code was just a hack.

If while testing application is hitting development database, then config/database.yml file need to be checked to ensure that it's not pointing to same db for test and development.

Comment: That solves the immediate problem of missing users, but is the code from the book wrong or is something in my configuration erroneously letting the tests hit the development database?

Comment: Please check your config/database.yml file. Which database have you specified for test?

Comment: The database.yml had the same database as test and development. I had run a migration after I changed the name to the test database and then everything worked. Thanks @Bot.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use something like [Database Cleaner](https://github.com/bmabey/database_cleaner). Then you would not need to delete the users manually but all the changes to the database would be automatically reverted (when using the transaction strategy).